# How to add vertical divs inside horizontal divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div align="center" id="menu_bar">
    <div class="menu_item"><a href="index">Home</a></div>
    <div class="menu_item art">
         <a href="art">Art</a>
         <a class="photography" href="photography">Photography</a>
         <a class="drawing" href="drawing">Drawing</a>
         <a class="painting" href="painting">Painting</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item"><a href="film">Film</a></div>
    <div class="menu_item"><a href="blog">Blog</a></div>
    <div class="menu_item"><a href="about">About</a></div>
    <div class="menu_item"><a href="contact">Contact</a></div>
</div>
```

jQuery/CSS:

```
$('#menu_bar div').css("display","inline");
```

This jquery puts each div horizontally but I want the `.art` a tags to be organised vertically so it ends up looking like this:

[image]

I have tried adding this:

```
$('.art').css("display","block");
```

But this makes the menu look like this:

[image]

Which is not what I want.

Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaop347b/) of my attempt

### Edit:

I have also tried:

```
$('.art a').css("display","block");
```

Which has ended up making it look like this:

[image]

Getting closer...

## Edit 2:

Thank you @Paulie_D is there anyway to prevent this gap (that I highlighted red):

[image]

Comment: You should be rethinking the HTML structure because it's not logical at the moment,

Comment: Really? Any ideas on a better structure?

Comment: Why not use a standard `ul`& `li` menu / sub-menu structure?...It's been the optimal menu structure for years for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An odd arrangement, but you can do it if you set the menu items to float and adjust spacing:

```
#menu_bar div {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.art a {
    display: block;
}

#menu_bar div:first-child {
    margin-right: -1.5em;
}

#menu_bar div:nth-of-type(3) {
    margin-left: -2.5em;
}
```

See [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/waat501s/)

Comment: But this means I need the menu to be aligned to the left?

Comment: No, you can position it any way you like. For example, I created a variation that centers it: http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/waat501s/2/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript for such a simple task, just add some a second level menu, wrap around the children and attach a some styles like:

```
    #menu_bar > .menu_item {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#menu_bar .submenu{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vaop347b/1/

Answer (score 0):

A standard `ul` & `li` structure would serve you better I'd suggest.

A basic example is as follows. Additional styling is, of course, required but the required layout effect is achieved.

```css
.navbar {} ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.main-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative
}

.sub-menu {
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translateX(-50%);
 }

.sub-menu > li {
  text-align: center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>

      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor.</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't add additional requests to existing questions once the original problem has been resolved as it may invalidate any existing answers. You should make a new question instead.

Comment: It was barely an additional request. If you look at the initial question I showed you how I wanted it, with an image.